# Can I use same C# windows application controls for Python Visual studio development

Tags: python, visual-studio, ironpython

I want to drag visual studio controls from its tool box and write python code
on its events. I am not sure that I am thinking correct. For example, drag
one simple text box and button and like double click to open the c# coding window,
somehow I should write python code instead. I am not asking anyone to do my homework but need an assurance that I am going to do correctly because VS is a very is easy IDE unlike others